# Integrating over norm-$t$ ideles in Tates thesis

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{A}^\times$ denote the group of ideles of a number field $K$, $d^\times x$ the multiplicative Haar measure on $\mathbb{A}^\times$, $f$ an adelic Schwartz function, and $\mathbb{A}^\times_t$ the i
deles with norm $t$.

When proving the functional equation, you introduce the following function:

$$Z_t(f) = \int_{\mathbb{A}^\times_t}f(x)d^\times x$$
then write the zeta integral as
$$Z(f, s) = \int_0^\infty t^s Z_t(f)\frac{dt}{t}.$$

What does the function $Z_t(f)$ look like when $K$ is not simply $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{A}^{\times}$ is not the ring of adele but the group of idele. It is the multiplicative group of the ring $\mathbb{A}$ endowed with a special topology making it into a locally compact group.

Comment: Yes I meant to write ideles and that $\mathbb{A}^\times_t$ are the ideles with norm $t$